# PySide2 Tear Off Tabs

Tags: mouseevent, pyside2

The project is to have a main window GUI with tabs, and the ability to tear off tabs into their own floating main windows.  Exactly like the Chrome browser I'm using right now (probably most/all browsers do this).  Using Windows 10, Python 3.7.7, PySide2 5.15.0.

I'm looking at similar questions here and elsewhere that use the native C++.  They all seem to have one thing in common: Picking up mouse events on the tab.

I can create a subclassed QTabWidget and do all the things that pick up mouse events, for instance, putting a "installEventFilter()" in the class' "__init__()", and an "eventFilter()" function.  Or simply overriding the "event()" function.  I can pick up all kinds of events, including mouse events, *but not on the tabs*.  Click/move in the tab view, yes; click/move next to the existing tabs on the tab bar, yes; but click/move on the tabs themselves produces "Paint" events.  This is correct, as the tab view must be repainted when the tab is selected.  But I can't pick up a mouse event for use in the dragging techniques I see in the C++ code.  I can't pick up the mouse event that results in the Paint event.

Apparently, in native C++, the mouse events can be intercepted before they get to the tabs.  I'm not seeing a way to intercept mouse events on the tabs in PySide2.

Comment: Have you tried subclassing QTabBar and use [setTabBar](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QTabWidget.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QTabWidget.setTabBar) ?